# Convert "keyof GenericType" to string

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write an interface like this:

```
interface IGFilter<T> {
  [key: keyof T]: GQuery | IGFilter<T>,
  _NOT?: GQuery
}
```

However I keep getting the error: `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`. Why is this? If keys can only be strings or numbers, then why does it think `keyof T` is not a string or number? Shouldn't `keyof Type` always result in string or number?

What is the correct way to make an interface that includes all properties of the generic interface type passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
type IGFilter<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: GQuery | IGFilter<T>
} & {
  _NOT?: GQuery;
}
```

Takeaways:

- Restrict `T` to be of type `object` by doing `T extends object`
- To iterate over keys of a generic type, use mapped types: `{ [K in keyof T]: ... }`
- When using index signatures (like `{ [key: string]: Foo }`), all right-hand side properties must conform to the type `Foo`. If you want to mix properties of different kinds, use a type alias and intersect it with another type (as per my solution).
- `keyof T` can be one of 3 things: `string`, `number`, or `symbol`